# How do I add Traits to weapons?

Tags: atelier-lydie-and-suelle

I've tried crafting weapons a couple times now, but I haven't been able to find any traits that'll transfer to weapons. I definitely remember being able to add traits in previous Atelier games, so what's going on? Did they nerf weapons?

Answer (score 1):

Weapon crafting is a bit different in Lydie & Suelle. Weapons are separated into three parts, two of which are optional (kinda): the base weapon, the core, and the sub component. Base weapons, which are crafted through the "Craft Weapon" option in Hagel's shop, cannot hold Traits. Rather, base weapon stats are affected by their ingredient Effects. Notice that certain items such as Ingots have Effects such as "Craft Equip - ATK S". These Effects determine the stats of the base weapon when used in crafting.

Once you have acquired a base weapon, you can add cores and sub components to it through the "Customize Weapon" option in Hagel's shop. Cores and sub components are how weapons gain Traits in Lydie & Suelle. These parts are swappable, allowing you to easily transfer valuable and painstakingly obtained traits with less fuss. In addition to Traits, cores and sub components often have their own Effects that are added on top of the Traits that they provide.

Note that Traits on cores and sub components can be combined on a weapon. For example, if you have Skill Power +10% on a Cabochon Gear and Skill Power +12% on a Bravery Alliance, they can combine for Enhance Skills on if you equip them on the same weapon.